# Responsive images resizing issue with bootstrap 3 and IE 10

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-10

I've searched the forum already but haven't seem to be able to find the answer. My images are fine in FF, Chrome, and IE 11, however, in IE 10, my images take up the entire page even though they are only about 300px wide. I'm using bootstrap 3 with the Joomla Purity III template. I see the hack in the css already: width: 100% \9. I tried removing the height of auto but this seems to have made my images disappear. What would be the best/easiest solution to this problem?

```
 article img,
.article-intro img {
  display: block;
  width: 100% \9;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.img-responsive,
.thumbnail > img,
.thumbnail a > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100% \9;
  background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-radius: 0;
   /* line-height: 1.42857;*/
    padding: 4px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.img-responsive-left {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100% \9;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-radius: 0;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
.img-responsive-right {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100% \9;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-radius: 0;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    padding: 4px;
}
.img-left-borderless {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100% \9;
    max-width: 300px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    padding: 4px;
}

.img-rounded {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.img-thumbnail {
  padding: 4px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100% \9;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: have you got a fixed width on the image, if not you could use bootstraps own class, img-responsive on the image

Comment: jsg, I tried that before but unfortunately it didn't stop the images from becoming huge in ie 10

Comment: Just a note, this is an issue with the template styles, not Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution? Just remove `width: 100% \9;`, it's a hack.

A more robust solution is to ensure that the css won't affect images if their dimensions are already set (as they are when inserting images with the image editor), eg:

```
/* Don't ignore `width` and/or `height` attributes if present. */
img[width],
img[height] {
    max-width: none;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Seth, thanks for your reply. This might be a stupid question, but should I get rid of the max-width: 100%; on all of these images?

Comment: No, you probably don't want that. That would mean they can't be scaled down on screens that are smaller than the image, causing the image to 'break out' of the side of your website.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring `max-width: 300px` and you can overwrite any defaults by tagging `!important` at the end of it.

`max-width: 300px !important`

If that doesn't work, then it would be helpful to see more code to understand your context.

Comment: The only problem with that is not all of my images are the same size. I can provide some of the code but wasn't sure how to properly add it to this thread?

Comment: Your code has to have four spaces in front of it in order to show up on stack overflow as code.  It's kind of annoying but it works.

Comment: I went back and edited my original question. Are you able to see the code that I added? thanks

Comment: I can see the code. It's hard to know exactly what is happening without also seeing the html. Do you have a link I could see of the exact situation? I would probably be able to help you much faster that way.

Comment: Hi Barry thanks so much for your response. I think I figured it out (at least for now). I added width: auto instead of width: 100%. Not sure if this will cause other issues or not? I'm using Bootstrap 3 with Joomla's Purity III template and I'm not fully sure which pieces of html to include?